# Prevent overload explosion when accepting permutations of user-defined-literals

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a struct `Dimensions` which has templated arguments for width and height:

```
template<unsigned W, unsigned H>
struct Dimensions
{
    static constexpr unsigned width = W;
    static constexpr unsigned height = H;
};
```

I have `Width` and `Height` classes which have templated arguments for their respective values:

```
template<unsigned N>
struct Width
{
    static constexpr unsigned value = N;
};

template<unsigned N>
struct Height
{
    static constexpr unsigned value = N;
};
```

I have created user-defined-literals for width and height

```
template<char... cs>
constexpr auto operator""_w() -> Width<to_unsigned(0, parse(cs)...)>
{
    return {};
}

template<char... cs>
constexpr auto operator""_h() -> Height<to_unsigned(0, parse(cs)...)>
{
    return {};
}
```

where `to_unsigned` and `parse` turn the chars into an unsigned value

```
constexpr unsigned to_unsigned(unsigned p)
{
    return p;
}

template<class... Ts>
constexpr unsigned to_unsigned(unsigned val, unsigned v, Ts... vs)
{
    return to_unsigned(val * 10 + v, vs...);
}

constexpr unsigned parse(char C)
{
    return (C >= '0' && C <= '9')
        ? C - '0'
        : throw std::out_of_range("input is not a number");
}
```

As such, I can now create a function template which takes `Width` and `Height` instances created from string-literals, and returns a `Dimensions`

```
template<unsigned W, unsigned H>
constexpr Dimensions<W, H> dimensions(Width<W>, Height<H>)
{
    return Dimensions<W, H>{};
}

auto d = dimensions(5_w, 10_h);

static_assert(d.width == 5, "");
static_assert(d.height == 10, "");
```

I want to allow the user to be able to provide only one dimension (the other being 0), or to provide the literals in a different order.

The way I have currently implemented this is to have a number of different overloads:

```
// width, height
template<unsigned W, unsigned H = 0>
constexpr Dimensions<W, H> dimensions(Width<W>, Height<H>)
{
    return Dimensions<W, H>{};
}

// height, width
template<unsigned H, unsigned W = 0>
constexpr Dimensions<W, H> dimensions(Height<H>, Width<W>)
{
    return Dimensions<W, H>{};
}
```

If I now add a third dimension, `Breadth`, the number of `dimensions` overloads will explode, as they way I have currently implemented it requires one overload for every possible permutation.

**Question:**

Is there a way to allow the user to specify dimensions using any combination/ordering of width, breadth and height, omit some, etc?

(Working example of the above code on coliru [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9177b4d5e65b83e2))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most direct way is to start with a metafunction to search for a specific dimension:

```
template <template <unsigned> class Z, class... Ts>
struct find_dimension;

template <template <unsigned> class Z, class... Ts>
using find_dimension_t = typename find_dimension<Z, Ts...>::type;

// found it
template <template <unsigned> class Z, unsigned N, class... Ts>
struct find_dimension<Z, Z<N>, Ts...> {
    using type = Z<N>;
};

// keep going
template <template <unsigned> class Z, class T, class... Ts>
struct find_dimension<Z, T, Ts...> 
    : find_dimension<Z, Ts...>
{ };

// default to 0
template <template <unsigned> class Z>
struct find_dimension<Z>  {
    using type = Z<0>;
};
```

Then we just use it:

```
template <class... Dimensions>
auto dimensions(Dimensions... ) {
    using height = find_dimension_t<Height, Dimensions...>;
    using width = find_dimension_t<Width, Dimensions...>;
    using breadth = find_dimension_t<Breadth, Dimensions...>;

    return Dimensions<width::value, height::value, breadth::value>();
}
```

---

A cleverer way might be to take advantage of inheritance:

```
template <template <unsigned> class Z, unsigned N>
constexpr unsigned get_dim(Z<N> d) { return N; }

template <template <unsigned> class Z>
constexpr unsigned get_dim(... ) { return 0; }

template<class... DimensionTs>
auto dimensions(DimensionTs...)
{
    struct X : DimensionTs... { };
    static constexpr X x {};

    return Dimensions<
        get_dim<Width>(x),
        get_dim<Height(x),
        get_dim<Breadth>(x)
    >();
}
```

The nice feature of the second one is that duplicate dimensions are a compile error.